# How to write a testcase for this?

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs

This is the code which I need to write the test case. I need to write a test case using jest.
I wrote a test case for check the POST route of save message. but it is not working. It shows " TypeError: app.address is not a function" error message.

model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    const messageSchema = new Schema(
      {
        user: {
          type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Staff'
        },
        writerName: { type: String, required: true },
        date: { type: String, required: true },
        description: { type: String, required: true },
      },
      {
        timestamps: true,
      }
    );
    
    //mongodb data table name
    const Message = mongoose.model("Message", messageSchema);
    
    module.exports = Message;
```

controller

```
const Message = require("../models/Message.Model");
const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");

const saveMessage = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const {writerName, date, description} = req.body

  const mesg = new Message({
    user: req.user._id,
    writerName,
    date,
    description
  })

  const createMsg = await mesg.save()

  res.status(201).json(createMsg);
})

module.exports = {
  saveMessage,
};
```

route

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { protect } = require("../middleware/authenticationMiddleware")
const { saveMessage } = require("../controllers/message.controller");

router.route("/save").post(protect, saveMessage);

module.exports = router;
```

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");
const messageRouter = require("./routes/message.routes");
const { notFound , errorHandler} = require("./middleware/errorMiddleware");

dotenv.config();
connectDB();
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("API is Running");
});

app.use("/api/message", messageRouter);

app.use(notFound);
app.use(errorHandler);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(5000, console.log(`server is running on PORT ${PORT}`));
```

db.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            
        });
        console.log(`MongoDB connected: ${conn.connection.host}`)
      
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Error: ${error.message}`);
        process.exit();
    }
};

module.exports = connectDB;
```

.env

```
MONGO_URI=
JWT_SECRET=
```

This is the test case which I had written

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const request = require("supertest");
const server = require("../server");

require("dotenv").config();

/* Connecting to the database before each test. */
beforeEach(async () => {
  await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);
});

/* Closing database connection after each test. */
afterEach(async () => {
  await mongoose.connection.close();
});

describe("POST /api/message/save", () => {
  it("should create a message", async () => {
    const res = await request(server).post("/api/message/save").send({
      user: "2",
      writerName: "wN",
      date: "12",
      description: "Description",
    });
    expect(res.statusCode).toBe(201);
    expect(res.body.name).toBe("Message 1");
  });
});
```

This is the error which I had

```
> backend@1.0.0 test
> cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --testTimeout=5000

  console.log
    server is running on PORT 5000

      at Object.log (server.js:34:26)

  console.log
    MongoDB connected: ac-asr02at.mongodb.net

      at log (config/db.js:10:17)

 FAIL  test/test.js
  POST /api/message/save
    × should create a message (1328 ms)

  ● POST /api/message/save › should create a message

    TypeError: app.address is not a function

      19 | describe("POST /api/message/save", () => {
      20 |   it("should create a message", async () => {
    > 21 |     const res = await request(server).post("/api/message/save").send({
         |                                       ^
      22 |       user: "2",
      23 |       writerName: "1009",
      24 |       date: "Description 2",

      at Test.serverAddress (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:46:22)
      at new Test (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:34:14)
      at Object.obj.<computed> [as post] (node_modules/supertest/index.js:43:18)
      at Object.post (test/test.js:21:39)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.101 s
Ran all test suites.
```

Comment: Can you put the full error (stacktrace)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are importing your server like this:

```
const server = require("../server");
```

But you are not exporting anything from that file. You need to modify it to export your express `app`

```
module.export = app;
```